# Was there a change in timezone for ToLocalTime

Tags: asp.net-core-3.0

Currently I'm using `ToLocalTime` to convert the UTC date received from my backend. Is there a way to setup my ASP.NET Core 3.0 web site to use a specific timezone when calling ToLocalTime (instead of depending on the host region) -- or should I implement my own method/extension to converting to the time I need?

Answer (score 2):

Official documentation of [DateTime.ToLocalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netframework-4.8#examples) states:

> Note that the exact output depends on the current culture and the local time zone of the system on which it is run.

You can use the [TimeZoneInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=netframework-4.8) static method [ConvertTimeFromUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeZoneInfo_ConvertTimeFromUtc_System_DateTime_System_TimeZoneInfo_) to convert an instance of `DateTime` (Note: if it's `Kind` property is `Local` you'll get an exception!) from Utc to whatever local time you want (Another note: the `Kind` property of the result is either `Utc` or `Unspecified` - depending on the target `TimeZoneInfo`).

Code example (copied from documentation page):

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
try
{
   TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
   DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
   Console.WriteLine("The date and time are {0} {1}.", 
                     cstTime, 
                     cstZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(cstTime) ?
                             cstZone.DaylightName : cstZone.StandardName);
}
catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The registry does not define the Central Standard Time zone.");
}                           
catch (InvalidTimeZoneException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Registry data on the Central Standard Time zone has been corrupted.");
}
```

Comment: Okay, I hoped that there was a way to "override" the system time zone. I was looking at some of the options in `RequestLocalizationOptions`, but was not able to control is using this approach.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.requestlocalizationoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Note: This code will fail if run on a linux box. You should instead use: `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? "Central Standard Time" : "America/Chicago"))`. Or, even better, use the NodaTime library, instead of the CLR types here.